# PHP json_encode "<n"

Tags: php, json

I just faced weird behaviour while im using json_encode.

EDIT : Im using php 5.4.4 on debian with apache, this is the only line on the php file, nothing else, and its working okey on the command line php, basically its like this ;

```
<?

echo json_encode("B}c5KUKv;?Ch?D_{>wFU\ZV&ScMPorb;brVu&~N:!p.Sz~^xO#<<JOkK_j~u:WH1");
```

thats it. and here is the result in chrome html source code ;

```
"B}c5KUKv;?Ch?D_{>wFU\\ZV&ScMPorb;brVu&~N:!p.Sz~^xO#<
```

[solved] : It seems it was a content type issue. Anyway, i just add header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); and everything goes back to normal.

Thank you Lekensteyn please answer this question and i will accept it as answer.

Comment: What is your `Content-Type`?

Comment: You could try `htmlentities` before you use `json_encode`

Comment: How are you *viewing* the json?

Comment: Do not look at it in a browser, your browser expects HTML, not json (if you look at the source you can see everything is _fine and dandy_).

Comment: @scrowler If anything, you would use `htmlentities` *after* (if you want to view the output as HTML).

Comment: @Lekensteyn : Content type : header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @scrowler : didnt try to use htmlentities but the case is i need to know is there any special character which json_encode can't handle and why?

Comment: @WesleyMurch what you mean? on crome? i don't get what you mean. Basically i want to know is there any character json_encode can't handle and why.

Comment: @Wrikken of course i'm looking at source not html.

Comment: @Abides Cannot reproduce on PHP 5.5.5 with `php -r 'echo json_encode("asdfasdfasdf<nasdfasdfasdf");'`. Are you really using the same test code? `text/plain` is the wrong type for JSON, it should be `application/json`. `htmlentities` should not be used for JSON either... Look in the PHP manual.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I just removed everything on code even the content type, i didnt reproduce the error on shell too but just please use 5.4.4 if you can and please just create a php file and serve it with apache.

Comment: @Lekensteyn only you undestand my question and actually have idea about what is going on. Thank you, you are the man. Please answer my question and i will accept it as success. If you use my code above without any content type or text/plain json encode drop rest of the code, i just change it to application/json and its solved. Please answer and i will give you what you deserve. Rest of the people still trying to figure it out what im asking...

Comment: @Abides Are you sure that PHP is to be blamed? Could it be an Apache module? I have never heard of your behavior before. Can you reproduce it with other PHP versions and/ or webservers? Have you tried rebooting? (jk)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I can't get it to mis-behave either

http://codepad.org/TVuExbm0

Comment: Is codepad using latest version of php? I forget to say you need to add header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); i also cant replicate the error using codepad. Im using php 5.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this using PHP 5.5.4

It works as expected and outputs the json encoded representation of the entire string.

Maybe if you are using an older version of PHP, you might need to pass an option to json_encode, which is detailed in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Sorry i forget to say its 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

and im using php 5.4.4